# ImportError: No module named pyreadability in conda env

Tags: python, conda

in my python code I've got the line:

```
from pyreadability import pyreadability as pyrb
```

And I'm getting the error :

```
ImportError: No module named pyreadability
```

I'm in Ubuntu, using python 2.7 and running code inside a conda env named mzh27. 
I already tried these commands but none of them made the error solve

```
pip install PyReadability
conda install -c anaconda lxml
/home/{usr}/anaconda2/envs/mzh27/bin/pip install PyReadability
pip install readability-lxml
/home/{usr}/anaconda2/envs/mzh27/bin/pip readability-lxml
```

In all of those cases, the module installed successfully but error was still there.
Any Idea what to do for it?

Comment: After installation completed, did you try to restart the shell and check?

Comment: @JimTodd Yes I did

Comment: What happens when you try pip install PyReadability?
Also, is the module name correct? It might be pip install readability-lxml

Comment: @JimTodd already tried that. using both local and global pip. check last two commands I listed in the question.
In all of those cases, the module installed successfully but error was still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the repository I've cloned was missing the file named `pyreadability.py`. The package was not the one I thought. It was implemented by the repository owner (who forgot to add files to the repository) and just have similar names to python packages that are available to install.